# Why is the default Ubuntu boot partition so small? How can I increase it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Recently I created a Ubuntu server. During install I accepted the default options. Installer creates a 236M `/boot` partition as shown below. After only a few months the partition is full. Is this partition not awfully small? How can I increase it?

```
$ df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                      16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs                    3.2G  524K  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ci--vg-root   95G   80G   11G  89% /
none                     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                      16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
none                     100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                236M  225M     0 100% /boot
```

Comment: This is not a programming related question and so is not appropriate for StackOverflow. Please use a different StackExchange site for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You boot partition is probably running out of space as a result kernel updates leaving the old kernels. Just remove the old unused kernels using the following command:

```
dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e '[0-9]' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

Take a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot) on Ask Ubuntu for more information

If this command fails because of "unmet dependencies" you first have to correct these using `apt-get -f install`. But that will also fail because of disk space. What you can try is to physically move some of the `initrd.img*` files out of the `/boot` directory to free some space for example

```
sudo mv /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-25-generic /tmp
sudo mv /boot/initrd...
```

You can find out current kernel versions using

```
uname -r
```

Answer (score 0):

Install GParted Partition Edition and use it for increase or decrease your boot partition

Answer (score -1):

That partition stores the data that is needed before the kernel is loaded (notably the bootloader) and it's size should not change...